# Probability: ensemble 3 algorithms

Tags: probability, outliers

I have three outlier algorithms, every alg. check the quality of disel engine as `1` or `0`. `1` means good quality and `0` means bad quality. If 1st alg. prediction accuracy rate is `80%`, 2nd alg. prediction accuracy is `85%`, and 3rd alg. accuracy is `90%`. What is the probability that engine is in good quality if all three alg. predict good quality? What is the probablity that engine is in bad quality if all three alg. predict poor quality? Are there some math formular?

Comment: Is this a study exercise?

Comment: No, this is serious research/industry topic. I have a project to predict disel engine's quality. I used 3 different outlier detection algorithms. Then I ensemble 3 algs. So I need to calculate if all three alg. predicts it is good quality, what's the real accuracy of the prediction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical problem could be solved using Bayes theorem. The probability that the engine is good under the condition that all three algorithms indicate "good" is

$P(G|1,1,1)=\frac{P(1,1,1|G)*P(G)}{P(1,1,1|G)*P(G)+P(1,1,1|B)*P(B)}$,

and, the probability that the engine is bad under the condition that all three algorithms indicate "bad" is

$P(B|0,0,0)=\frac{P(0,0,0|B)*P(B)}{P(0,0,0|B)*P(B)+P(0,0,0|G)*P(G)}$,

where $P(G)$ and $P(B)$ are the probabilities that the engine is 'good' and 'bad' respectively. In your case,

$P(1,1,1|G)=P(0,0,0|B)=0.8*0.85*0.9$, $P(1,1,1|B)=P(0,0,0|G)=(1-0.8)*(1-0.85)*(1-0.9)$,

but you didn't tell what is $P(G)$ or $P(B)$, where $P(G)+P(B)=1$. Without any information about this, we may assume $P(G) = P(B) = 0.5$. under this assumption, the two probabilities you are looking for are equal, that is,

$P(G|1,1,1)=P(B|0,0,0)= 0.9951$.

Otherwise, if $P(G)$ and $P(B)$ are not equal, you need to know their values.

Comment: The formular looks very reasonable. But my bad, I have no confidence to confirm it. Are there some expert could evaluate the formular and then give the points? Thank you very much. @user295357